# How do you check if someone joinsvoice channel in Discord and then send a dm to someone

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

What I want to do is that if someone joins a specific voice channel, I get a DM. I am new to coding(only have little experience) so I have to use the internet. My Code is a combination from the internet. I only got it to work that it prints something in the console when someone joins.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    targetID = bot.get_user(747390765428113418)

    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None: 
        print(" Member joined")
```

For clarification I want to send the message to myslef

Comment: Are you trying to send a message to yourself or the person who joined the VC?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. In order to send a message to yourself, you have to do `discord.Member.send()`. You also need to get the member object as the `get_user` method returns a user instead of a member.

```py
targetID = member.guild.get_member(747390765428113418) # Get member from guild
await targetID.send(f"{member.mention} has joined the VC {after.channel.mention}")
```

This will send to the user with the ID of `747390765428113418` as you specified in your code.

Comment: @bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    targetID = member.guild.get_member(747390765428113418) # Get member from guild
    await targetID.send(f"{member.mention} has joined the VC {after.channel.mention}")

this is my code now but i get this error: next comment because of character limit

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python39\DarkBot\HaDebot.py", line 107, in on_voice_state_update
    await targetID.send(f"has joined the VC")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Answer (score 0):

A changed your code a bit:

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None: #Checking member is joined (not left) from voice channel
        await member.send("Your message") #Sending message
```